# In Flume what does channel capacity for file-channel really mean?

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

New to flume...

I can see the channel capacity setting to be useful for memory channels but

a) what does it really mean for file-channels?
b) how should I use it?

Do I set it to ensure that the channel isn't running out of file-system space?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the excerpt in the book Apache Flume - Distributed Log Collection for Hadoop, the file-channel capacity is only limited by the size of your disk.